# Counting rows (Pivot Table VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I basically have some data and I need to count how many times each row (titled "Process") occurs (using VBA). I used the built-in Excel macro, and used a pivot table to count the number of instances of each row, however, the problem is that when I run the macro, it only returns the total count of process.

This is my code:

```
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DataSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets.Add
    newsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        DataSheet & "!R1C1:R" & FinalRow & "C52", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        newsheet & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable24", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets(newsheet).Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").PivotFields("Process")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable24").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable24").PivotFields("Process"), "Count of Process", xlCount
End Sub
```

If I remove the code between End With and End Sub, I get a pivot table with the rows as the list of processes. But when I add those two lines, I just get a value titled "Count of Process" with the Grand Total value. I am pretty sure that the issue lies somewhere there. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, can you show me an example of the data please?

Comment: Yes, let me save it and I'll send you a link

Comment: I can't save it as a url. But for example, these are all processes
Budgeting - FINANCE
Budgeting - FINANCE
Derivative Accounting - COMMERCIAL OPERATIONS & ENVIRONMENT
Derivative Accounting - COMMERCIAL OPERATIONS & ENVIRONMENT
Derivative Accounting - COMMERCIAL OPERATIONS & ENVIRONMENT
IESO Settlements - COMMERCIAL OPERATIONS & ENVIRONMENT
IESO Settlements - COMMERCIAL OPERATIONS & ENVIRONMENT

Comment: And each process appears a varying number of times. I need to count how many times each one appears

Comment: It is not clear to me why you want to use pivot tables in your code. If you just want the result can't you run a countif for each process on raw data? If you want the result in the form of pivot table can't you create a pivot table manually and just refresh it with vba?

Comment: Hi, I've just tried your code and it works fine (on a different data range of course). What I would try is to create the same pivot table on the same data but manually. If the same issue occurs when you pull the "Process" column into both your Rows and Values pivot fields, then the issue is within the data itself and not VBA.